# Busqueda binaria recursiva

Tags: java, array, busqueda

Tengo un quebradero de cabeza importante.

Estoy realizando una búsqueda dentro de un array y quiero que me indique la posición del elemento dentro del array, hasta el momento todo bien.

De hecho el código no presenta errores a simple vista, pero al usarlo me salta todo rojo rojo.

Mi código consta de dos clases (main y búsqueda) dentro de un paquete llamado arrays, para poneros en situación.

El código de **busqueda**:

```
package busqueda;

public class busqueda {

    public int buscar(int numeros[], int n) {
        int principio, fin, centro;
        principio = 0;
        centro = numeros.length / 2;
        fin = numeros.length - 1;
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while (principio <= fin || !encontrado) {
            if (numeros[centro] == n) {
                encontrado = true;
            } else if (numeros[centro] < n) {
                centro = -1; 
            } else {
                centro = +1; 
            }
        }
        if (encontrado) {
            return centro;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Y ahora el código de **Main**:

```
package busqueda;

import busqueda.busqueda;
import java.util.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        busqueda busca = new busqueda();
        int numeros[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int pos = busca.buscar(numeros, 8);
        if (pos > -1) {
            System.out.println("Encontrado en la posicion: " + pos);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Todo parece estar bien planteado, pero al ejecutar el ejercicio me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagino que el problema estará en la clase **busqueda**, pero no consigo verlo, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El algoritmo que aparece en el código mostrado no es [recursivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)), sino [iterativo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteraci%C3%B3n); un algoritmo recursivo debe incluir llamadas a sí mismo.

#### Algoritmo recursivo

Si la función `buscar` representa un [algoritmo de búsqueda binaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria) en su variante recursiva, el código debería ser similar al siguiente:

```java
public int buscar(int[] números, int número) {

    return buscar(números, número, 0, números.length);
}

public int buscar(int[] números, int número, int inicio, int fin) {

    int centro = (inicio + fin) / 2;

    if (fin < inicio) {
         return -1;
    }

    if (número < números[centro]) {
        return buscar(números, número, inicio, centro - 1);
    }

    if (número > números[centro]) {
        return buscar(números, número, centro + 1, fin);
    }

    if (número == números[centro]) {
        return centro;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

#### Algoritmo iterativo

Si, por el contrario, el título de la pregunta fuese incorrecto y se desease utilizar la variante iterativa incluida en el cuerpo de la pregunta, el código debería ser similar al siguiente:

```java
public int buscar(int[] números, int número) {

    int inicio = 0, fin = números.length - 1;

    while (inicio <= fin) {
            
        int centro = (inicio + fin) / 2;
            
        if (número < números[centro]) {
            fin = centro - 1;
        }

        if (número > números[centro]) {
            inicio = centro + 1;
        }
            
        if (número == números[centro]) {
            return centro;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

#### Algoritmo ya existente

Más allá de un posible pasatiempos o ejercicio de algorítmica, resultaría mucho más adecuado utilizar la versión ya incorporada en la librería estándar del lenguaje de programación Java:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
```

```java
public int buscar(int[] números, int número) {

    return Arrays.binarySearch(números, número);
}
```

Para más información, véase [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int)) en la documentación de Java.